# Run OnGetAsync Method when razor page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages, page-refresh

I am struggling to determine how to run the method shown in the code below when the razor page is refreshed, currently the method will only run when the page is initially loaded (this typically might be the user loading a different page and coming back to this one)

I need to run this method every time the user clicks the browser refresh button or hits the F5 button. I rely on pulling data from the DB that is then dictating what an icon status should be for a background service I'm running.

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        SystemMapping = await _context.SystemMapping
            .Include(s => s.ConnectorInbound)
            .Include(s => s.ConnectorOutbound).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var mapping in SystemMapping)
        {
            string mappingName = mapping.MappingName;
            if (ConnectorManagement.systemMappingStatusDictionary.TryGetValue(mappingName, out string status))
            {
                ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(mappingName, status));
            }
            else
            {
                status = "Stopped";
                ViewData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(mappingName, status));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Confused about what you mean . Is  the `OnGetAsync()`  the get request method of the razor page that you refresh ? If so , it will be called every time whether the page  initially loaded or refreshed . Could you share more logic of the razor page and the method in the backaround ?

Comment: If the user causes a POST when they refresh the page, add the code to the `OnPostAsync` method too. That should cover all options for you.

Comment: The OnGetAsync is only called when the page is initially loaded. The OnPostAsync method would only be called when a form is posted. I need a way of detecting when the page has been refreshed on the browser (but detecting this server side so I can then re-poll the database again using the code that is currently shown within the above code example) Refreshing the browser is not a form submission so therefore the OnGetAsync or OnpostAsync method will never be called. See http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/21633/is-it-possible-to-detect-a-page-refresh-f5-using-jquery

Comment: I'm unclear why you have used the JavaScript tag and referenced a forum item on jQuery in your comment. You haven't mentioned using either in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnGetAsync` method is run *whenever* the page is requested using the HTTP `GET` verb. If the page was initially loaded using `GET` (the default) then hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or clicking the refresh icon in the browser will result in another `GET` request, and the `OnGetAsync` method will be fired.

If the page was initially loaded using the `POST` verb, refreshing will result in another `POST` request, albeit with a browser warning about submitting the form first.

So what you are looking for is the default behaviour. You don't need to do anything at all.

Comment: Hi Mike, your feedback has highlighted something I need to look a bit more closely in my environment. I have two OnPost methods in my page model, tied to start and stop buttons on each row the my razor table. After pressing either button initiates the post command which explains why I get the browser 'warning about submitting the form first' when I then refresh the page. Perhaps I shouldn't be using an OnPost methods at all for this scenario given I'm not posting anything as such, am just using the method to run some server side code to start and stop one of my background services.

Comment: If you are changing state (which it sounds like you are) you should use post. In that case, my original suggestion stands - duplicate the code in the post handlers too, or better yet, refactor it to a separate method and call that in all handlers.

Comment: After 3hrs of investigation, I realized that each time I was refreshing the page, as Mike said I was in fact processing the OnPost method which in turn was trying to startup a service that was already running, and through my backend code was screwing up a cancellation task dictionary. Oh well got there in the end...